# How many essentially distinct hands of size $n$ can be dealt from a standard deck?

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

In many card games, suits are interchangeable, so that one would be indifferent between the (4-card) hands: $5\diamondsuit \ 6\spadesuit \ 7\heartsuit \ J\heartsuit$ and $5\spadesuit \ 6\diamondsuit \ 7\clubsuit \ J\clubsuit$. I'm interested in the number of $n$-card hands which are *essentially different*, that is, They are distinct under every possible relabeling of the suits. Put another way, two hands are essentially the same if there is some relabeling of the suits that makes them identical. Specifically, if it matters, I am most interested in the case $n=6$.

Lots of people have done similar calculations for $n=5$, due to the poker connection, but their analyses are always poker-centric. In particular, every general explication of $n$-card hands I've found assumes that one is going to make their best 5-card hand. I haven't been able to find any reference to this specific problem, and I'd really like to avoid having to do it from scratch.

Searching the broader internet and M.SE both turn up lots of specific homework-type problems looking for the number of one specific type of hand. Obviously one could enumerate all distinct 6-card hands ignoring suits and then count the ways to add suit-shapes to them; I'd really like to avoid that. Surely there's either a quick way to answer the question, or an answer out there somewhere already?

Comment: Are the rules clear?  Would you say that a straight flush is the same as  the straight with the same underlying ranks?

Comment: The fact that all of the cards have the same suit is important, but which suit they share in common is not. So in general a straight flush is different from a straight

Comment: Ok, well...is that the only instance in which suit matters?

Comment: No, in every case the "shape" of the suits matters, but the specific suits does not. Framing this in terms of poker makes it less clear. The idea is that two hands are essentially the same if there is some relabeling of the suits so they are identical.

Comment: Got it.  But in that case I think some case work will be required.

Comment: I hope you're wrong :(  But thanks for looking!

Comment: In the example you speak about 3 card hand but show 4 cards. Why?

Comment: because the question is in need of editing, thanks!

Comment: [here](https://oeis.org/A181430), I think, is the numerical answer for $n$ ranks (but $5$ card hands and $4$ unlabeled suits). One of the associated references appears to claim a general formula.

Comment: @lulu I think you're right! Of course it comes down to generating functions. It happens I've just finished working it out the long way, so hopefully the numbers will match. Please feel free to make that an answer and I'll mark it solved. Thanks!

Comment: I would if I had checked the proposed result, which I have not.  No time to do it now, maybe later.

Comment: I would also be interested in seeing that the reference found by lulu and the "long way" answer by dbx agree, with a little bit more details and numerical values.  In fact, @dbx - what is your numerical answer (no. of essentially diff hands) for $n=6$?

Comment: @antkam my hand calculation was wrong - as I expected it would be; I'm really not very good at these calculations. I've got a brute force solution working and it matches the reference in lulu's comment; I'll write up a quick answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment by @lulu, it appears that the answer is given by the coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion of the *$4$th Complete Bell Polynomial* $$B_4(\{0!\cdot(1+x)^{13}, \ 1!\cdot(1+x^2)^{13}, \ 2!\cdot(1+x^3)^{13}, \ 3!\cdot(1+x^4)^{13}\})$$ divided by $6!$. Here is the *Mathematica* code I used to generate the polynomial, and its result:

```
y1 = (1 + x)^13;
y2 = (1 + x^2)^13;
y3 = 2 (1 + x^3)^13;
y4 = 6 (1 + x^4)^13;
p = BellY[4, 1, {y1, y2, y3, y4}] + BellY[4, 2, {y1, y2, y3}] + 
    BellY[4, 3, {y1, y2}] + BellY[4, 4, {y1}];
Expand[p]

24 + 312 x + 4056 x^2 + 42120 x^3 + 394368 x^4 + 3227016 x^5 + 23111712 x^6 + ...
```

Giving the solution 23,111,712 / 24 = **962,988** distinct hands.

This solution is based on the "Formula" comment found at the OEIS link [here](https://oeis.org/A181430). I haven't been able to find another reference for it, but using a brute force algorithm, I was able to confirm the result.

Comment: I mentioned in the comments to the original question that I had attempted a calculation by hand -- I did not get the correct result that way (which is not surprising).